# obligation of someone who reads a Psak Din sign in the street

Tags: halacha, rabbis, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Suppose I read a sign in the street headed **Psak Din** which says that such-and-such a thing is forbidden (these signs never say such-and-such is permitted), with the names of a list of rabbis at the bottom that supposedly agree on this.

Can I ignore it?  Should I go to the great effort of confirming that the rabbis really did agree to this? Does it automatically follow that if the rabbis really did agree on this, that I personally have to follow it?  Do I have to follow it out of "sofeik" (doubt)?

Related question: Is it permitted to intentionally **avoid** reading such signs?

Comment: Putting them up in the first place is forbidden ([source](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_1dvjR1OTKao/TA0LEdmo-tI/AAAAAAAAAqI/zvze7yuGrxI/s1600/pashkevil_hebrew.jpg) / [English](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_1dvjR1OTKao/TA0LJ3Sf78I/AAAAAAAAAqQ/JhlNe1gwRYs/s1600/pashkevil_english.jpg)).

Comment: @IsaacMoses The [Beer Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=889&st=&pgnum=415&hilite=) forbids it also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pashkvillim (unsigned papers) that don't have a source are no more reliable than J.SE answers (if anything it would be worse as people try to bring sources here). As with all halachic advice from unknown individuals CYLOR before acting.

Comment: "unsigned papers" - but the question is talking about papers with names underneath. Or are you equating them?